# Create a lambda expression from list, where each item is OR'ed

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm not sure if this is even possible but the following code works:

```
searchDescriptor.Query(q => firstQuery || secondQuery || thirdQuery);
```

But I have these passed into my method from a list myOrQueries, so I need to do something like:

```
List<Query> myOrQueries; // includes the 3 items above

// what I need is the correct way of doing the line below - if possible??
searchDescriptor.Query(q => myOrQueries[0] || myOrQueries[1] || myOrQueries[2]);
```

Is it possible to select each item and OR it somehow?

Comment: Do you mean Union it?

Comment: No, don't think so. I need to be able to do something like: `q => myOrQueries.ForEach(||)` or similar. Basically OR'ing the list.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a smart LINQ provider will be able to work with the array directly, something like this:

```
searchDescriptor.Query(q => myOrQueries.Any())
```

If that isn't good enough, you'll just have to slap those queries together using `OrElse`, and use them as a single predicate in `Where` on the original searchDescriptor.

This is a bit lengthy, so I'll just refer you to Joe Albahari's `PredicateBuilder` helper class: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

It helps to add those as extension methods on `IQueryable`, they're quite handy :)

**EDIT**:

A simple solution that works:

```
BaseQuery variableQuery = null;

if (roleStatuses != null && roleStatuses.Any())
{
  foreach (string roleStatus in roleStatuses)
  {
    var status = roleStatus;
    var subQuery = 
        new QueryDescriptor<MySearchDataContract>()
        .Match(s => s.OnField(o => o.Roles.First().RoleStatus)
                     .QueryString(status));

    variableQuery = variableQuery == null ? subQuery : variableQuery || subQuery;
  }
}
```

Comment: `Any` will only check that there is something in the list, assuming each item is an actual query then they would probably need to be executed e.g. `Any(x => x())`.

Comment: `searchDescriptor.Query(q => myOrQueries.Any())` will match every item as long as `myOrQueries` at least one element. It should be `searchDescriptor.Query(q => myOrQueries.Any(x => x(q))`

Comment: Well, I have no idea what those queries are, so I can't write the "completely correct" code, I'm just outlining the reasoning. Most likely something like `searchDescriptor.Query(q => possibleValues.Contains(q.SomeField)` will be a better fit.

Comment: @Luaan I think the problem is you are suggesting that `Any` should just "work", when in actual fact all `Any` does is determine that there is *something* in the list, it in no way evaluates the value of that particular item in the list (which is what the OP is looking for).

Comment: .Any() is not what I'm looking for. See my frist line (which works) - I need to get to that same output using a list. I'll have a go at the PredicateBuilder and let you know. Thanks

Comment: @user3796750 How is that different from using `Any(x => x == true)`? I'm finding it hard to penetrate your pseudo-code, what is that `Query` object in reality? In any case, make sure that you're not doing something needlessly complicated, I've not encountered a problem that would require me to join general queries together yet - it's usually quite easy to separate those into a bunch of where's with the `||`'s being known at compile-time.

Comment: PredicateBuilder is not an option after testing. My query's are type BaseQuery from Nest-ElasticSearch but not important really. My Search method accepts a list of queries - so I need to split these out and OR them somehow. Doesn't look possible using lambda syntax it seems? So plan B - is having to hardcode the lambda expression which stops the method from accepting a dynamic list of search criteria. Sad face.

Comment: If your queries aren't `Expressions`, you're quite a bit more limited, but it's still doable. You'll just have to build an expression that `||`'s the invocations of the sub-queries. All in all, though, it seems as if your design was a bit sub-optimal. Why aren't you just using `Expression`s / `Func`s to specify the query?

Comment: @Luaan - building the expression was the way forward, see my edit. Cheers

Comment: @user3796750 You should create an answer and accept it, rather than editing it into the question. Also, are you sure it works? I see a closure on the iteration variable, which might cause the query to be composed of X times the last query.

Comment: I'm not allowed to add an answer as a newbie sorry. There's no closure on the iteration variable as there's no delegates being used within the loop. What have you spotted? I've tested and it works as well.

Comment: @user3796750 The `Match` method is not evaluated lazily? You're capturing `roleStatus` inside of that lambda.

Comment: Very good spot! It wasn't breaking my code and the output results (after testing) but I've copied it out to a separate variable to be safe. Can you copy my edit into a new answer and I'll mark that as correct please? Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments from Luaan - lambda was a no-go but a simple foreach to build the expression works:

```
BaseQuery variableQuery = null;

if (roleStatuses != null && roleStatuses.Any())
{
  foreach (string roleStatus in roleStatuses)
  {
    var status = roleStatus;
    var subQuery = new QueryDescriptor<MySearchDataContract>()
                          .Match(s => s.OnField(o => o.Roles.First().RoleStatus)
                          .QueryString(status));

    variableQuery = variableQuery == null ? subQuery : variableQuery || subQuery;
  }
}
```